# Changing SQLite DB Version

Tags: sqlite

Is there a way to check and/or update the dbVersion while inside sqlite3?

Looking for the equivalent of extJS `db.version` and `db.changeVersion()` from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

There is a #pragma statement that the database has built in which can be used to maintain a version of the database called 'user_version'. A link to some information can be found here  [user_version](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version/)

The sql query for setting the user version is:

```
PRAGMA user_version = 1;
```

This sets the user_version and then every time the database/application starts this can be queried. Note: The user_version must be set before any tables or records are created within the database. It can be queried anytime after that though in order to find out the current version.